# Use current cell as IF statement and a variable

Tags: excel

I am trying to run this if statement which works if i enter it as a new column giving me correct data

```
=IF( A107 = "CRM",[@TranAmt]*-1,[@TranAmt])
```

However I want to do this query in cell [@TranAmt] using the data that is already in cell [@TranAmt] without creating a new column of data and i am unsure how to do this without creating a new row and adding it to the top of the row, which i would like to avoid.

Comment: When would cell `A107` ever contain `CRM` if it contained `[@TranAmt]`? Logically, what you are trying to do can not be done.

Comment: Sorry My mistake i mean in the cell [@TranAmt], not A107. meaning if the cell in row A = CRM then turn the vale into [@TranAmt] into a minus.

Comment: So you want to cell `A107` to modify the contents of `[@TranAmt]`? That can't be done. Everytime the workbook would recalculate `[@TranAmt]` would be recalculated and multiplied by -1 which would trigger another recalculation.

Comment: Cell A107 will either be CRM or something else, i want that IF cell a107, etc is CRM that the value in [@TranAMT] will run [@TranAmt]*-1 and if not it stays the same as it is now. I can do all this in another collum, but im trying to do the calculation in the [TranAmt] Columm. This is a static excell doc also, ive pulled this data from SQL server